How to insert concated column lines after import a table in an org file?
I read a table from a txt file as follows. How to add a line that concat specific rows after import the table? Are there any built-in functions to shorten the script?
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
  (org-table-import "ttt.out" nil)
#+end_src

The file ttt.out will be:
#Cluster   Frames   Rep RepScore   Rep RepScore
       0      23      2      0.6     6      0.4 
       1      10      5      0.1     3      0.5
       2       5      4      0.4     5      0.6
       3       4      1      0.4     2      0.6

The results I need (concat the Frames column by commas, @2..@5).
| #Cluster | Frames | Rep | RepScore | Rep | RepScore |
|        0 |     23 |   2 |      0.6 |   6 |      0.4 |
|        1 |     10 |   5 |      0.1 |   3 |      0.5 |
|        2 |      5 |   4 |      0.4 |   5 |      0.6 |
|        3 |      4 |   1 |      0.4 |   2 |      0.6 |
- query: "23,10,5,4"


Please review the [help] and in particular How to ask as well as the guidance for what’s on-topic.
